# How can i retrieve date time available per second in one day?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, for-loop, multidimensional-array

my input is date.
But, i'm stuck on how to retrieve date time in every second. 
I need to put the each second date time in the 2d array.so my array(0,0) should equal to 2/10/2014 00:00:00 AM and array(86399,0) is equal to 2/10/2014 23:59:59 PM.

i tried do looping as per below code:

```
Dim twoDarray(86399, 1) As String
Dim dtInput As Date

dtInput= #2/10/2014#
For i=0 to 86399

   twoDarray(i, 0) = dtInput 
   dtInput = dtInput +second 'i know this not right

Next
```

I just don't know how to increase date time every second in right way.
Please help.

Comment: This seems excessive.  Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: @zira the given solution does not working in your case?

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about something along the lines of

Using a Datetime (MSDN [Datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
dtInput= new DateTime(2014,10,2)
For i=0 to 86399

   twoDarray(i, 0) = dtInput 
   dtInput = dtInput.AddSeconds(1)

Next
```

Or

```
dtInput= new DateTime(2014,10,2)
For i=0 to 86399

   twoDarray(i, 0) = dtInput.AddSeconds(i+1)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following method also

```
Dim dtFrom As New DateTime(2014, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0)
Dim dtTo As New DateTime(2014, 10, 2, 23, 59, 59)


Dim iFirstDim As Integer = (dtTo - dtFrom).TotalSeconds
Dim iSecondDim As Integer = 10
Dim arrTime(iFirstDim, iSecondDim) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
Do While (dtTo > dtFrom)
    arrTime(i, 0) = dtFrom.ToString("d/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    dtFrom = dtFrom.AddSeconds(1)
    i += 1
Loop
```

**HOW TO USE IT?**

```
Dim dtResult As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(arrTime(150, 0), "d/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtResult) Then
    MsgBox(dtResult.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
End If
```